# Most efficient way to make one attribute of a table into the attributes of another table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

**Situation:** Lets say we 2 tables. TableA and TableB.

TableA:

- A_id
- A_name

**Question:** What would be the most efficient way in terms of design to make the values of "A_name" all the columns of TableB?

**Example:** If A_name contained: "Foo", "Foo1", "Foo2" then TableB should look like:

TableB:

- Foo
- Foo1
- Foo2

Comment: The number of rows from TableA is the same number of columns from TableB?

Comment: No, the values of the second column in TableA will become the columns in TableB.

Comment: How many rows will TableB have? Is that determined in advance or it should be able to accept any number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating a new table, whose columns are going to be driven by the contents of TableA?

There are several products out there that will let you construct a model of the table(s) to be built, interactively and visually.  Then, you can invoke a function that generates a script to create the table(s).  Each of these products will store the info you are string in TableA in a spearate database, one whose subject matter is the model for the real database.